# How to match datas between two tables in a database?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with client and guest table. both table have client_icNum and guest_icNum. these client and guest is the same person. 
now i want to know what sql should i do to make the client_icNum will be recognized that it is  the same as guest_icNum?

Answer (score 1):

First query:

Get all client present in guest

```
SELECT c.*
FROM client c
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM guest g
    WHERE c.client_idNum = g.guest_icNum
)
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM client c
JOIN guest g
ON c.client_idNum = g.guest_icNum
```

Second query:

Get all client not present in guest:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM client c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM guest g
    WHERE c.client_idNum = g.guest_icNum
)
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM client c
LEFT OUTER JOIN guest g
ON c.client_idNum = g.guest_icNum
WHERE g.guest_icNum IS NULL
```